# pytesseract hang when use french language

Tags: python, tesseract, freeze

I have a small code with pytesseract. It works well for english version but when I change to french language, it doesn't work (the program hang). Thank for your help!

Here is my code:

```
import pytesseract
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
   from PIL import Image
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.jpg'), lang='fra')
print text
```

I have `fra.traineddata` in the same folder of `eng.trainedata`

Comment: Did you make sure to install Tesseract correctly? The code looks fine, so it may be a problem with your installation.

Comment: I tested for the same file test.jpg, it Ok for english but when I add lang='fra' the program hang and it not return the result. If Tesseract not install correctly how it can run in case of english by default ? Thank !

Answer (score 1):

In the function `run_tesseract`:  I'm not sure why someone thought appending  tuple to a string would work.  I replaced

```
command += ('-l', lang)
```

with

```
command += "-l '" + lang + "'"
```

And it worked.